# Compare date in dimension table against multiple dates in fact table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a calculated column in Power BI desktop that is comparing a date in one table to (potentially) multiple dates in a different table related by some key. Specifically, I have a customer dimension table that contains one row per customer ID, like so

| CustID | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1/1/2000 |
| 10001 | 1/1/2000 |
| 10002 | 1/2/2000 |

and a fact table that contains sales information with relevant fields like so

| CustID | OrderDate |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 2/1/2000 |
| 10000 | 2/2/2000 |
| 10001 | 1/1/2000 |
| 10002 | 3/15/2000 |

where there are multiple records per customer.

I want to create a calculated column in the dimensional table that returns 1 if the customer has made a purchase within the following 3 months of when their account is created or 0 otherwise. The criteria is as follows:

- If a customer's purchase was in July, I want to know whether they bought again in either Aug, Sept, or Oct.
- If they bought twice in July, that doesn’t count. Just looking for whether they came back in Aug-Oct.
- Customer's his first purchase date doesn’t matter at all, except for the month. So July 1 first purchasers and July 31 first purchasers are exactly the same.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
IF(
   OR(
      AND(DIM_Customers[Second Order Date].[Month] <> DIM_Customers[DateFirstPurchase].[Month], DATEDIFF(DIM_Customers[DateFirstPurchase], DIM_Customers[Second Order Date].[Date], MONTH) <= 3),
      AND(DIM_Customers[Third Order Date].[Month] <> DIM_Customers[DateFirstPurchase].[Month], DATEDIFF(DIM_Customers[DateFirstPurchase], DIM_Customers[Third Order Date].[Date], MONTH) <= 3)
      )
      , 1, 0
   )
```

This gives me results, but the issue I'm running in to is it doesn't account for instances when their first few purchases are within the same month and later purchases are within the expected conditions. I don't know how to compare the created date in the Customer table to multiple dates in the Sales table to see if they've made a purchase. If I just compare to the `MIN`, `MAX`, or even some date in between it is not giving me the correct results as some customers have one purchase while others have multiple, all within varying timeframes.

Not sure if I'm on the right track or if I need to abandon completely and go another route (must use calculated column though).

Comment: Can you supply a sample .pbix?

Comment: You can use the [Adventure Works data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms) from Microsoft as a sample as it is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you help clarify...

- Whether they made a purchase over the next three months of their account created or first purchase?

Maybe try something like:

```
calcColumn = 
  var dateInit = [createdDate] // or change to first purchase date
  var dateFrom = DATE( YEAR(dateInit), MONTH(dateInit) + 1, 1) // following month
  var dateTo = EOMONTH(dateFrom, 2)
  var purchases = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Fact Purchases table'), 'Fact Purchases table'[OrderDate] >= dateFrom && 'Fact Purchases table'[OrderDate] <= dateTo)
  RETURN IF(purchases > 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: In this particular scenario, `Account created` = `first purchase date`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The answer above should work - give it a go a let us know how it goes.